Python returns "None" when using =SUMIF with OpenPyXL
I'm trying to write a program that stores player stats and returns averages whenever my "Refresh Statistics" button is clicked.
My program
My code:
def refresh_stats():
    wb = load_workbook(filepath, data_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    print(ws['E2'].value)

When I hand jam my excel function with no user input based data in the excel file, it returns fine:
Output before using program user input
However, when I use my program to write to the excel file, it returns "None".
Output after user input ingested into excel
Here's my "Enter data" function for more info:
def enter_data():
    player1 = player1_combobox.get()
    damage1 = p1_entry.get()
    player2 = player2_combobox.get()
    damage2 = p2_entry.get()
    player3 = player3_combobox.get()
    damage3 = p3_entry.get()
##Print function only for console
    if (player1 == ''):
        pass
    else:
        print(player1, "did", damage1, "that game!")

    if (player2 == ''):
        pass
    else:
        print(player2, "did", damage2, "that game!")

    if (player3 == ''):
        pass
    else:
        print(player3, "did", damage3, "that game!")

    print("-------------------------------------")

##Creates the excel sheet if it does not already exist
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active
        heading = ["Player", "Damage"]
        sheet.append(heading)
        workbook.save(filepath)

##Export data if BIZ is a player
    if player1 == "Biz":
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
        sheet = workbook.active
        sheet.append([player1, int(damage1)])
        workbook.save(filepath)
        print(f"{player1}'s data has been saved!")
    elif player2 == "Biz":
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
        sheet = workbook.active
        sheet.append([player2, int(damage2)])
        workbook.save(filepath)
        print(f"{player2}'s data has been saved!")
    elif player3 == "Biz":
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
        sheet = workbook.active
        sheet.append([player3, int(damage3)])
        workbook.save(filepath)
        print(f"{player3}'s data has been saved!")
    else:
        pass

I'm not really sure on what to try as I'm new to Python and OpenPyXL. I originally had my "Refresh Stats" function within my "Enter data" loop but I pulled it out to see if that would work with nothing. :c

Openpyxl just edits the underlying XML files, it does not and cannot evaluate formulas.Therefore the value of the formula is None until the Excel workbook is opened in Excel. You may be better off to use Xlwings or Win32com which will open the workbook in Excel for editing.
